# REACT: onChange callback not firing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, callback, onchange

The onChange callback isn't firing when the user chooses a different select option. I'm using react-bootstrap as my FE component library. I've tried structuring the callback differently (ex. as a string etc.) but haven't had any luck. Thanks in advance!

JSX:

```
                  <Form.Group as={Col} hidden={!showSegments} controlId={segmentId} className="required">
                    <p>I am teaching in this space:</p>
                    <select ref={segmentSelect} name="segmentId" onChange={toggleSchoolBoardVisibility}>
                      { segments.map((x) => (
                          <option value={x.segmentId}>{x.name}</option>
                        )
                      )) }
                    </select>
                  </Form.Group>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const toggleSchoolBoardVisibility = () => {
  console.log('hi')
}
```

EDIT: The onChange function is located in the same component. If I replace onChange with onBlur or onFocus, the callback gets called and works as expected.

Comment: have you try an inline function onChange={()=>toggleSchoolBoarVisibility()} ?

Comment: Yes. No luck :(

Comment: `select` is a react-bootstrap control?

Comment: This code works for me. Please provide a reproducible example of the code not working so we can try to help. In React all of the code is JavaScript, what you're referring to as HTML is JSX (JavaScript). Please provide more context such as the location of the change function.

Comment: See the working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-dream-6ocyz?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: @BrianThompson I've edited my question. Please let me know if that clarifies the issue.

Comment: @ARaj123 unfortunately that doesn't help. As shown in the codesandbox, the `onChange` does work under normal conditions. So we need to have a running example from you that shows it not working so we can test with your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum code that works flawlessly. [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zw3aj8b6/1/).

I think you aren't using the function callback correctly.

```
const SelectBox = ({ options }) => {
  const onOptionSelect = (e) => {
    console.log("selected", e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <select onChange={(e) => onOptionSelect(e)}>
        {options.map((opt, key) => (
          <option key={key}>{opt}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const myOptions = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

ReactDOM.render(
  <SelectBox options={myOptions} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use react-select..its efficient and easy to use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select